# Can't send a List inside a complex object to an ASP.NET MVC Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to pass a complex object to a .NET MVC controller from a View and i'm using Razor to do so. Here is my link:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("PlayVideo","Media",m)">
```

where "m" is an object of type MediaVM like this:

```
public class MediaVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public VCMediaType MediaType { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public string ThumbPath { get; set; }
    public List<string> Sources { get; set; }
    public string  Description { get; set; }
    public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
    public string PatientFullName { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is with the "Sources" property; because it is a List of Strings, when i call the action at the "MediaController" it receives the MediaVM object correctly constructed except for the Sources property, which just contains a Collection with one String with the literal "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]".

The Constructor:

```
public ActionResult PlayVideo(MediaVM videoMedia)
{
    return PartialView("Player", videoMedia);
}
```

How could i pass the complete list of strings? Is it possible?

Comment: By default, the framework injects the string as you have posted. one work around is to replace "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" with "Sources=val1,val2,val3" and assign this variable to href. eg. <a href="@hrefLink">